# what is the difference between xtol and ftol to use fmin() of scipy.optimize?

Tags: scipy

I'm starting to use the function fmin with a very simple example and I try to get the values ​​of a vector that minimizes the value of their multiplication:

```
def prueba(x,y):
    print "valor1:",x[0],"\n"
    print "valor2:",x[1],"\n"
    print "valor3:",x[2],"\n"
    print "valor4:",x[3],"\n"
    min=x[0]*x[1]*x[2]*x[3]
    print min
    return min

sal = fmin(prueba,x0=array([1, 2, 3,4]),args="1",retall=1,xtol=0.5,ftol=0.5)#maxfun=1,maxiter=1,retall=1,args="1")
```

but if I dont define xtol and ftol appears:

```
"Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded."
```

For this reason I have defined the convergence of the algorithm using the parameters `xtol` and `ftol`,but i still don't understand what is the difference between them, I look the same, but if I delete one of the two I get the warning again.

What exactly is the difference of `xtol` and `ftol`?, Which should use in this case?.

I have read the documentation:

> OtherParameters
>
> xtol : number
>           acceptable relative error in xopt for convergence.
>       ftol : number
>           acceptable relative error in func(xopt) for convergence.

I still do not understand

Answer (score 5):

Here's my understanding.  It's similar to the mathworks function [fminsearch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fminsearch.html).  They define these values:

TolFun: Termination tolerance on the function value
TolX: Termination tolerance on x

As the search proceeds in its iterative fashion.  The difference in the values of `x` from one iteration to another become smaller and smaller, until it doesn't matter any more and you might as well be done.  Same goes for the function tolerance.  In your example, `prueba` is evaluated and the difference between its return value from iteration to iteration gets smaller and smaller, until it doesn't matter either.  You asked which you should use.  This can bit a bit of an experimental approach.  In the past I have often used:

```
xtol = 1e-6;
ftol = 1e-6;
```

It seems to scale well to many problems, and is a good place to start.  You will likely find that if one needs to be tweaked, it will be obvious.  Like horrid convergence times.  Poor goodness of fit in the data, etc.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Therefore it would be possible to indicate ONLY the error minimum accepted between one iteration and another (ftol) to determine convergence and not to define the acceptable error to xtol leaving this default? fmin(prueba,x0=array([1, 2, 3,4]),args="1",retall=1,ftol=0.00001)

Comment: Yes, that will likely solve your problem.  Don't forget to hit accept on this answer if it solves your problem!  :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is, if indicated: fmin (test, x0 = array ([1, 2, 3.4]), args = "1", retall = 1, ftol = 0.6, xtol = 0.6) the solution is: 383 Optimization terminated successfully. 384 Current function value: 0.016163 385 Iterations: 23 386 Function evaluations: 42 .But indicated only fmin (test, x0 = array ([1, 2, 3.4]), args = "1", retall = 1, ftol = 0.6) warning appears, why?

Comment: The default values for `ftol` and `xtol` is 0.0001 for each, when you set `ftol` smaller than `xtol` during the search, `xtol` is exceeded before `ftol` is reached so it terminates prematurely.  I should have looked at your question closer, forgive.  I would recommend always setting both.

Comment: Thank you very much and I feel upset again. I think I understand your reasoning but when I define only ftol = 0.6, ftol is BIGGER than default xtol set to 0.0001, so in this case ftol will be fulfilled before xtol and I dont' see any problem but appears the warning. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a bit old, but still I want to point out that @user1264127's example simply does not converge.  Depending on the specific details of the fmin algorithm, this example may be diverging exponentially.  If you want to see the differences between xtol and ftol, try a convergent example, like this:

```
def myFun(x):
    return (x[0]-1.2)**2 + (x[1]+3.7)**2

optimize.fmin(myFun,[0,0])
```

The output when I run with default parameters:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: 0.000000
     Iterations: 79
     Function evaluations: 150
Out[4]: array([ 1.19997121, -3.70003115])
```

The output when I run with xtol=1e-12:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: 0.000000
     Iterations: 138
     Function evaluations: 263
Out[5]: array([ 1.2, -3.7])
```

And with xtol=1, ftol=1e-3:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: 0.000099
     Iterations: 61
     Function evaluations: 116
Out[17]: array([ 1.20348989, -3.69068928])
```