# Custom convergence criterion in scipy optimise

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am optimising a function using `scipy.optimize` in the following manner:

```
yEst=minimize(myFunction, y0, method='L-BFGS-B', tol=1e-6).x
```

My problem is that I don't want to stop simply when the tolerance is less than a value (e.g. if on the nth iteration stop is `|y_n - y_(n-1)|<tol`). Instead I have a slightly more complex function of `y_n` and `y_(n-1)`, say `tolFun`, and I want to stop when `tolFun(y_n, y_(n-1))<tol`.

To give more detail my tolerance function is the following. It partitions `y` into chunks and then checks if any of the individual partitions have a norm difference within tolerance and, if any do, then the minimisation should stop.

```
# Takes in current and previous iteration values and a pre-specified fixed scalar r.
def tolFun(yprev,ycurr,r):

  # The minimum norm so far (initialized to a big value)
  minnorm = 5000

  for i in np.arange(r):

    # Work out the norm of the ith partition/block of entries
    norm = np.linalg.norm(yprev[np.arange(r)+i*r],ycurr[np.arange(r)+i*r])

    # Update minimum norm
    minnorm = np.min(norm, minnorm)

  return(minnorm)
```

My question is similar to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363501/setting-convergence-criteria-for-scipy-optimize-fmin-and-others) but differs in the fact that this user needed only the current iterations value of `y`, whereas my custom tolerance function needs both the current iterations value of `y` and the previous value. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do directly what you want since the callback function receives only the current parameter vector. To solve your problem you can modify second solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30365576/8033585 (which I prefer to the first solution that uses `global`) in the following way or so:

```
class Callback:
    def __init__(self, tolfun, tol=1e-8):
        self._tolf = tolfun
        self._tol = tol
        self._xk_prev = None

    def __call__(self, xk):
        if self._xk_prev is not None and self._tolf(xk, self._xk_prev) < self._tol:
            return True

        self._xk_prev = xk
        return False

cb = Callback(tolfun=tolFun, tol=tol)  # set tol here to control convergence
yEst = minimize(myFunction, y0, method='L-BFGS-B', tol=0, callback=cb)
```

or

```
yEst = optimize.minimize(
    myFunction, y0, method='L-BFGS-B',
    callback=cb, options={'gtol': 0, 'ftol': 0}
)
```

You can find available options for a solver/method using:

```
optimize.show_options('minimize', 'L-BFGS-B')
```

Comment: Ah I see! Brilliant! Thank you! That's exactly what I was hoping for! Just to clarify though, why is it that you return `True`/`False` here. The example referenced raises an exception to stop the minimisation running... can returning `True`/`False` achieve the same thing here?

Comment: @JDoe2 See documentation for `callback` in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html for details. It says: _"If callback returns `True` the algorithm execution is terminated."_ hence no need to trow exceptions to end execution

Comment: Ah I see... going by that documentation I thought that is only for optimization with ‘trust-constr’ though?

Comment: @JDoe2 No, it applies to any `callback`. The `'trust-constr'` thing affects only function signature