# Minimise a multivariate function using scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to minimize this multivariate

[image]

where αi are constants (could be both positive or negative) and n is fixed,
using the `scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs` function.

Conditions:

- Test the code for a random natural number n between 5 and 10
- A random starting point (all of the form m.dddd)
- Do the iterations till the successive iterates are less than 2% in
  absolute value, in the l∞ norm.
- The coefficients αi (of the form m.dddd) should be chosen randomly so
  that at least 40% of them are negative and at least 25% of them are
  positive.

This is what I have tried (for custom callback refered to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30365576/7906671),

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import fmin_bfgs

#Generate a list of random positive and negative integers
random_list = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1, 10))[0].tolist()
p = []
n, npr = [], []
for r in range(len(random_list)):
    if random_list[r] < 0:
        n.append(random_list[r])
        npr.append((str(random_list[r]), 0.4))
    else:
        p.append(random_list[r])
        npr.append((str(random_list[r]), 0.25))

#Function to pick negative number with 40% probability and positive numbers with 25% probability
def w_choice(seq):
    total_prob = sum(item[1] for item in seq)
    chosen = np.random.uniform(0, total_prob)
    cumulative = 0
    for item, probality in seq:
        cumulative += probality
        if cumulative > chosen:
            return item

#Random start value with m.dddd and size of the input array is between 5 and 10
n = np.random.randint(5, 10)
x0 = np.round(np.random.randn(n,1), 4)

alpha = []
for i in range(n):
    alpha.append(np.round(float(w_choice(npr)), 4))

print("alpha: ", alpha)

def func(x):
    return sum(alpha*(x**2.0))

class StopOptimizingException(Exception):
    pass

class CallbackCollector:

    def __init__(self, f, thresh):
        self._f  = f
        self._thresh = thresh

    def __call__(self, xk):
        if self._f(xk) < self._thresh:
            self.x_opt = xk

cb = CallbackCollector(func, thresh=0.02)
x, _, _ = fmin_bfgs(func, x0, callback=cb)
```

But this does not converge and gives the following :

`Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.`

I am not able to figure out why this fails. Any help is appreciated!